# Bind inner directive to its parent form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

Having a directive, `my-drtv` , with `<input ng-required="true">` within `<div ng-form="myForm">` .

Currently the inner `ng-required` isn't bind to its form (`myForm`) , how could I set to `my-drtv` the same form as its parent ?

(so that in the initial state `myForm.$valid` should be false)

**JS:**

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myAppModule', []).
    directive('myDrtv',function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A', 
            template: '<div><input ng-required="true"></div>'
        }
    });
```

**HTML**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myAppModule">
<body>  
    <div ng-form="myForm">
        <div my-drtv>
        </div>
        <br>
        {{myForm.$valid}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have validation behaviour input fields must have both ngModel and name attributes. Then it will be registered as control under form controller. So you could do

```
.directive('myDrtv', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div><input name="inp" ng-model="inp" ng-required="true"></div>'
    }
});
```

or better pass model and name from outside, then directive will become much more reusable:

```
.directive('myDrtv', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            return '<div><input name="' + attrs.name + '" ng-model="model" ng-required="true"></div>';
        }
    }
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<div ng-form="myForm">
    <div my-drtv name="some" ng-model="someField"></div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/FV7jeiuLvqPmIlVyyXWr?p=preview